# Is this query possible without subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

> Set the credit limit on all customers to 0 when the customers When
>   they got a reminder in 2008 and 2009

The simplified tables

```
Create table customer (id int, credit_limit int);
Create table Bill (id int, customer_id int, date datetime);
```

My approach:

```
Update customer 
   set credit_limit = 0 
where (select customer_id 
       from bills 
       where year(reminder) = 2008) 
  and (select customer_id 
       from bills 
       where year(reminder) = 2009)
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Your `create table ` statements don't match your update query (`bills` vs. `bill`,  `date` vs. `reminder`). There is also no data type `datetime` in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE customer set credit_limit = 0 
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            bills
        WHERE
            bills.customer_id=customer.customer_id
            AND year(bills.reminder) IN (2008,2009)
    )
```

Or if you want to check that both 2008 and 2009 exist existing. Then you can do

```
UPDATE customer set credit_limit = 0 
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            bills
        WHERE
            bills.customer_id=customer.customer_id
            AND year(reminder) = 2008
    )
    AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            bills
        WHERE
            bills.customer_id=customer.customer_id
            AND year(reminder) = 2009
    )
```

Comment: How is that not a subquery? Does oracle somehow optimize away the select?

Comment: Yes it is a subquery. But with a join you need to scan all the values. With an exists it will stop when it has an match. I just think that is is not necessary to join when he is not using the values in the update statement. And also with the risk of having a one to many relation between customer and bill. He will update more values then needed with a join then a exists. Therefor it made me believe that a exists is fast then a join

Comment: +1: EXISTS is a "semijoin", and would be either faster (or at least not slower than a join) as you say.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick in Oracle:

```
update
    (
    select
        c.id,
        c.credit_limit,
    from customer c
        inner join Bill b1 on
            c.id = b1.customer_id and year(b1.date) = 2008
        inner join Bill b2 on
            c.id = b2.customer_id and year(b2.date) = 2009

    ) up
set up.credit_limit = 0
```

Comment: You will need to select the primary key columns from the `customer` table (in the inner select), otherwise this won't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible without a sub-query (short of using `MERGE` - but that would still be something like a sub-query).

You can simplify your sub-query to make it more efficient (and correct)

```
update customer 
  set credit_limit = 0
where id in (select customer_id
             from bills 
             where extract(year from reminder) in (2008, 2009)
             group by customer_id
             having count(distinct extract(year from reminder)) = 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Update customer set credit_limit = 0
Inner join Bill b1 on customer.id = b1.customer_id
join Bill b2 on b1.customer_id = b2.customer_id  and year(b1.reminder) = 2009 and year(b2.reminder) = 2008
```

Comment: That's not valid for Oracle